# Xamarin.forms cross platform stopwatch for ios

Tags: xamarin.forms, stopwatch

I am totaly new to the mobile development. I need a example for stopwatch. My project is based on the crossplatform xamarin.forms and running ios as main platform. Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.NET API Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/) is a great resource where you can find everything you need and in most cases with examples.

From the .NET API Browser:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
    }
}
```

Full documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netstandard-2.0).

P.S.: The link I shared targeting .NET Standard 2.0